# Como capturar parâmetro passado via factory do Angular JS em página PHP

Tags: php, angularjs

Como capturar [numa página em PHP] o valor do `input` abaixo utilizando `factory` do AngularJS?

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="edicao" ng-model="edicao" 
value="<?php if(isset($_GET['edicao'])){echo $_GET['edicao'];}else{}?>" />
```

AngularJS:

```
factory.autosave = $resource('actions/autosave.php', {}, {});
```

Comment: tentar assim  factory.autosave = $resource('actions/autosave.php', {edicao: $scope.edicao}, {});  Assim ele vai mandar um objeto json no body da requisição que possui o atributo "edicao"  e o valor dele.

Comment: Olá @HugoLima, acontece que o `factory.autosave` está fora do `controller`. Ou seja, `$scope is not defined`.

Comment: No seu controller deve ter a factory instanciada, é no controller que você manda os objetos para a requisição.... Factory.autosave.get({edicao: $scope.edicao},{},function(retorno){//logica});